# How to get the gsp file stored under grails-app/views/teamplates directory and modify it in Grails

Tags: html, grails, grails-2.0

I have created a file "_emailTemplate" in "grails-app/views/teamplates" directory.Its a html template file, The content of the file is below,

```
<html>
  <strong>Client: </strong>${client}<br/>
  <strong>Training: </strong>${training}<br/>
  <strong>Dates: </strong>${dates}<br/>
</html>
```

I want to load this file and replace the placeholders with the specific values like

```
${client} with the value of client variable etc.
```

How to do this.

Comment: Grails is not an acronym - it's "Grails", not "GRAILS".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render this template to a string. In any controller you can use this code:

```
def output = g.render(template: "/templates/emailTemplate", model: [client: 'John', training: 'Tennis', dates: 'tomorrow'])
```

`g` is a injected RenderTagLib instance. If you want to use it inside a service you must create an instance for yourself like this:

```
def renderTagLib = new RenderTagLib()
def output = renderTagLib.render(template: "/templates/emailTemplate", model: [client: 'John', training: 'Tennis', dates: 'tomorrow'])
```

Comment: Or use the `groovyPageRenderer` Spring bean, which you can autowire into services in the normal way.